# muting all sound on hover elements

Tags: button, audio, hover, mute

I'm working on a site that plays short sounds whenever the user hovers over text:  http://www.kalliopimathios.com/

I followed this tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/examples/SoundOnHover/

however, the sounds can dominate the page and I'm trying to add a simple mute/unmute toggle button so the user can choose to have a silent experience.

this tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_prop_muted worked for a single audio clip (and you'll see i put the buttons on the bottom of the website i'm working on), but how can i use a button to override all audio?

Thank you!!